# X11/XQuartz problem on 10.8.2

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

On my Snow Leopard iMac, X11 is broken. I get:

> dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_DGifGetLine Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libGIF.dylib in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO

when trying to run an OpenGL executable and http://codepad.org/HzjwS9wh when I try to run X11 directly.

I've reinstalled X11 from the original discs and the same thing happens, so I install XQuartz:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-XYA2Ul/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

$ launchctl list | grep xquartz
-       0       org.macosforge.xquartz.startx
```

This fails as well and I get http://codepad.org/NGowe0UR

I update to Mountain Lion, the problem persists, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing XQuartz on ML solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page.](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2010-November/022662.html)

It suggest trying `sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib /opt/local/lib/libGIF.dylib` in Terminal.

(in your case; this exact command is not on the linked page)

Comment: installing ML solved the issue

Comment: @nyiotis glad it's working now! Can anyone test this to make sure that this works, too?